# How do I kill an Android thread completely?

Tags: android

I have a service that has its own thread running on background. I'd like to kill that service including the thread.

I created the thread like this and run it.

```
 public class DaemonService extends Service {

     private DaemonThread thread;
     class DaemonThread extends Thread {
          public void run()
          {
               runDaemon(mArgv.toArray(), mConfig);
          }
     }

     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
          thread = new DaemonThread();
          thread.start();
     }
 }
```

How do I kill the service and the thread as well? I don't have to worry about data safety..

Comment: Your saying your thread doesn't stop. are you sure the runDaemon(mArgv.toArray(), mConfig); method doesnt spawn another thread inside it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

to kill the thread , i think you can do like this :

```
myService.getThread().interrupt();
```

**NOTE :**  the method `Thread.stop()` is deprecated

**EDIT :** : try this

```
public void stopThread(){
  if(myService.getThread()!=null){
      myService.getThread().interrupt();
      myService.setThread(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: @LYCSoft, how is the thread still alive? Show us the code in runDaemon(mArgv.toArray(), mConfig);

Comment: @Houcine can i ask u , which is  myService  here.. ?

Comment: @RaghavChopra : myService is your Class that extends the Service , in this case , myService is an instance of the class : DaemonService

Comment: @Houcine well i have  method name fnExpand how can i kill my thread
at the start of methos and its calss name is XYZ

Comment: Can u please have a look on ma code i need 2 kill thread in my uncaughtException Method  how can i kill it ? code is in here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240962/how-to-handle-the-exception-in-android-with-given-code

Comment: you need to check for interrupt in the thread if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException();//or exit etc
}

Answer (score 7):

The method `Thread.stop()` is deprecated, you can use
`Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` and then set `thread=null`.

Answer (score 1):

use [`Context.stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) or `stopSelf()` method of the Service.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the service's onDestroy method

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy%28%29)

```
 public void onDestroy(){

         thread.stop();
         super.onDestroy(); 
 }
```

Then stop the service with stopService(); (this will invoke onDestroy());

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: the method *Thread.stop()* is deprecated , you can use *Thread.interrupt();*

Comment: Sorry :p switch it out for intterupt then :-)

Comment: Thread.interrupt() is not necessarily enough... that method will indicate that the thread has been interrupted and some calls will terminate early / immediately due to this flag (as long as it is not cleared), however the thread itself doesn't automatically terminate. The thread needs to have code to detect this condition and terminate itself (returning from the run() method).

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

Comment: -1 because onDestroy may not always be called, for example; when the System is low on resources it won't call the method. This should be put in onStop.

Comment: @Loligans if the system has terminated your app without calling `onDestroy()`, believe me, that thread is not going to keep running.

Comment: is there a way to kill all threads and destroy app at the push of a button?