# How to force stop thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I have PublishSubject for observing status change and also I have method with multiple steps, which I execute in another thread. How I can force stop this thread when subject received changes?

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186537/how-do-i-kill-an-android-thread-completely

Answer (score 0):

In spite of stopping a thread, you can stop emitting new elements and release resources of your PublishSubject. Inside your PublishSubject add a check for isDisposed and if it is true - stop emitting and call onCompleted. From your code dispose of your PublishSubject. I hope it'll help.