# How to kill thread in Android Studio

Tags: android, background, onresume, onpause

Goal: I want to increment the counter when the app is in the background and when the app is now in resume the increment should stop, then the last value of the counter will be displayed in the screen.

Actual: but when I run my code, counter is successfully incremented if the app is in the background. But when I resume, the counter is still incrementing. How can I stop this thread if it is now in resume?

This is my code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.background;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;            
import android.widget.Button;            
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView timeTextView;
Button buttonCtr;
int counter=0;
boolean isResume;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeLbl);
    buttonCtr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ctrUp);

    buttonCtr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter++;
            timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        }
    });


}

class backgroundProcess extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(isResume == false ) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter);
        }

        System.out.println("LAST COUNT:" + counter);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isResume=false;
    System.out.println("IM IN PAUSE");
    System.out.println("IS RESUME: "+ isResume);
    new Thread(new backgroundProcess()).start();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    isResume=true; //to stop backgroundProcess Thread

    System.out.println("IM IN RESUME");
    System.out.println("IS RESUME: "+ isResume);
    System.out.println("LAST COUNT:"+ counter);
    timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

}
```

}

and this is my code for my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeLbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.397" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ctrUp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="196dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.475"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeLbl"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.54" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This question might be already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186537/how-do-i-kill-an-android-thread-completely

Answer (score 1):

2 things, here:

1. You are not using any synchronization primitives. This means the background thread's read of `isResume` is unreliable; it may appear to the background thread that `isResume` is `false`, even though the UI thread has already set it to `true`. In this particular instance, you should be able to declare `isResume` as `volatile`, and that will eliminate the [cache coherency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) problem.
2. You are dumping information to logcat at an extremely high rate, probably hundreds of thousands of lines per second (`System.out.println(counter)`). Android Studio has trouble reading & displaying logcat information at such a rate. It will usually lag behind, in this case, which can lead to the appearance that your thread is running, even though it has already stopped.

I should also mention that your access of `counter` is not threadsafe. Unlike `isResume`, you are doing read/write operations (`++`) on `counter` from both threads, so the `volatile` keyword is an insufficient fix. You must ensure all accesses to `counter` are protected by an actual lock (for example, by wrapping them in a `synchronized(MainActivity.this)` block).